# eclipse log disappears when android device is disconnected

Tags: android, eclipse, logging

While working on Eclipse, sometimes when I'm disconnecting the phone from the computer, the Eclipse log goes blank. It doesn't help when I reconnect my phone - I can continue working on it as before (compiling apk's etc.), but there is no log. The only way I have to fix it now is to restart Eclipse. Is anyone familiar with this problem and know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you shoild click your Device name in DDMS

Comment: Where exactly?
The device is working fine after reconnecting, it's just the log that is missing. So, are you sure this would help?

Comment: Yes, sometimes it helps me. I share screenshot from Eclipse http://www.fotohost.by/pic_b/13/10/25/eda4a83d6166f698a7d98faff780e852.png

Comment: Thanks for the effort loading the picture :) I'll give it a try next time this happens

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem with certain devices, and without having to restart Eclipse, the best solution is to close the log and reopen it through Window > Show View > Other > LogCat.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try next time this happens